# Mocking node-fetch with jest creating a Response Object for mocking

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, node-fetch

I am trying to create Response Objects for mocking with jest, I can't seem to get the right syntax.

Initialization,

```js
jest.mock('node-fetch')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const { Response, Headers } = jest.requireActual('node-fetch')

// Example adapted from https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#example-headers-class
const meta = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'Breaking-Bad': '<3'
}
// You can in fact use any iterable objects, like a Map or even another Headers
const headers = new Headers(meta)
const copyOfHeaders = new Headers(headers)

const ResponseInit = {
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'fail',
  headers: headers
}
```

With a basic test

```js
  test('Basic Test', async () => {
    const token = ''
    const getDocList = new Response(JSON.stringify(downloadDocumentData), ResponseInit)
    fetch.mockResolvedValueOnce(Promise.resolve(getDocList))
    await module.doSomething('mock', token)
      .then( async(res) => {
        await expect(res.data).toEqual(Object)
      })
  }, 5000)
```

I'm getting an error which is

```
     FetchError {
        message:
         'invalid json response body at  reason: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 2',
        type: 'invalid-json' }
```

How can I initial a response for valid json, I have tried a lot of different things.

Following the article at https://jestjs.io/docs/en/bypassing-module-mocks but I want to return and test json instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We should use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) to mock `node-fetch` module and `fetch` function.

In order to construct the response object of the `fetch` function, you need to use the `Response` class provided by the `node-fetch` module, so use [jest.requireActual(moduleName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename) to get the original, unmocked `node-fetch` Module and `Response` class.

Of course, we can construct the response object arbitrarily, but the instance of the `Response` class is really close to the real response.

The same goes for `headers` object.

Here is a working demo:

`index.js`:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = {
  async doSomething(url, token) {
    return fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
  }
};
```

`index.spec.js`:

```js
jest.mock('node-fetch');

const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const { Response, Headers } = jest.requireActual('node-fetch');
const mod = require('./');

const meta = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  Accept: '*/*',
  'Breaking-Bad': '<3'
};
const headers = new Headers(meta);
const copyOfHeaders = new Headers(headers);

const ResponseInit = {
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'fail',
  headers: headers
};

test('Basic Test', async () => {
  const token = '';
  const downloadDocumentData = { data: {} };
  const getDocList = new Response(
    JSON.stringify(downloadDocumentData),
    ResponseInit
  );
  fetch.mockResolvedValueOnce(Promise.resolve(getDocList));
  const res = await mod.doSomething('mock', token);
  expect(res).toEqual({ data: {} });
  expect(fetch).toBeCalledWith('mock');
});
```

Unit test result:

```bash
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58648691/index.spec.js
  ✓ Basic Test (5ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.557s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58648691

Comment: Does the automock setting in Jest affect this at all?

Comment: @jcollum I believe it needs to be set to false